# Looking for a better way use multiple pure functions to condense repetitive code

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I have a very large 3 dimensional dataset (named `pcapdata`) that I have broken down for data analysis. There are 7 smaller datasets contained in the main set.

My problem is that the data is arranged in a strange way, where there are 3 different sensors I must account for, and the rows of data alternate between the 3 sensors. After breaking down `pcapdata` into the 7 smaller datasets, I used pure functions to take the data of each sensor using the `Take`, and I repeated that 3 times for each sensor

```
papoints = 
  Take[pcapdata[[#]], {1, Length[pcapdata[[#]]], 3}] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
pbpoints = 
  Drop[Take[pcapdata[[#]], {2, Length[pcapdata[[#]]], 3}], -2] & /@ 
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
pcpoints = 
  Take[pcapdata[[#]], {3, Length[pcapdata[[#]]], 3}] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

These three lines grab every third row of data, starting from row 1, 2, and 3, respectively. Aside from the `Drop` function, these lines are about the same, aside from the (1, 2, 3). I was wondering if there were some way to use two pure functions (or something else) to reduce this down to one line. I have seen a few examples using `#1` and `#2` on this forum as well as mathematica's website. However, I couldn't get this to work on my own since my `#1` and `#2` were lists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If the 3 resulting datasets from these 3 lines were condensed into one variable, it would dramatically reduce the amount of code in other regions of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single pure function:

```
ClearAll[f]
f = #[[All, #2 ;; -#2 If[#2 == 2, 3, 1] ;; 3]] &;

{papoints, pbpoints, pcpoints} = f[pcapdata, #]& /@ Range[3]
```

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[d_, k_] := d[[All, k ;; -k If[k == 2, 3, 1] ;; 3]]
{papoints, pbpoints, pcpoints} = f2[pcapdata, #]& /@ Range[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?
I believe you'll get the same results..

```
T[x_] :=Take[s=pcapdata[[#]],{x,Length@s,3}]&/@Range@7
papoints = T[1]
pbpoints = {#}&@@@T[2]
pcpoints = T[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not as sophisticated nor as concise as kglr's, but I think it may be easier to understand.

First, for testing purposes, I contrive some data which I believe has the same structure as yours.

```
SeedRandom[42]; pcapdata = RandomReal[1, {7, 12, 3}];
```

Next I repeat your calculations with the test data to get validation set.

```
papoints =
  Take[pcapdata[[#]], {1, Length[pcapdata[[#]]], 3}] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7};
pbpoints =
  Drop[Take[pcapdata[[#]], {2, Length[pcapdata[[#]]], 3}], -2] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
pcpoints =
  Take[pcapdata[[#]], {3, Length[pcapdata[[#]]], 3}] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Now I do a single computation that computes the first and last result needed and an intermediate result for the second result.

```
{papts, tmp, pcpts} =
    Table[
      f /@ Range[7], 
      {f, Function[k, Take[pcapdata[[#]], {k, -1, 3}] &] /@ Range[3]}];
```

Finally, I compute the second needed result.

```
pbpts = Drop[#, -2] & /@ tmp;
```

#### Validation

```
And @@ {papoints == papts, pbpoints == pbpts, pcpoints == pcpts}
```

> `True`